# I’m looking for a 3-book science fiction series about human encounter and battle with aliens that happens on a submersible aircraft carrier

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

The three book series takes place on a submersible aircraft carrier which starts to have strange encounters with unknown creatures swimming in the ocean. As they continue to investigate, they encounter flying saucer UFOs, 50-year-old conspiracies and secrets involving previous encounters, and they capture and learn to operate the alien craft.

The sub-carrier has both an aircraft wing and a marine company onboard and eventually gains a group from a secret government group studying and working against the aliens.

I think there were several groups of bad aliens, some just worker animal like and the others really bad and a group of good aliens trying to keep worlds not ready from being preyed upon.

These books were written in the late eighties or early nineties, not totally sure.

Answer (score 8):

Is it the [Starsea Invaders](https://www.goodreads.com/series/119669-starsea-invaders) series by G. Harry Stine?

> The Pacific Island port of Makasar used to be a fairly peaceful outpost of the United States Navy. But now, entire American families are vanishing without a trace and no one has any ideas about where they might be. William M. Corry, captain of the super-sub U.S.S. Shenandoah has orders to get to the bottom of the mysterious disappearances. At first, he suspects the unpredictable Chinese troopers patrolling the area, but after a little investigating, Corry realizes that the disappearances of the Americans cannot be the fault of the Chinese--they are as worried as he is. Corry refuses to believe the wild rumors of native cannibals until he accidentally unearths the real enemy: a force with power beyond anything humankind has ever known!

This is a guess because I haven't read the books and I cannot find a copy to check. But the description sounds similar to yours. The description of the second book mentions:

> William M. Corry, captain of the American super-sub, the U.S.S. Shenandoah, was certain his new mission was not as simple as it first seemed. His initial orders were for a shakedown cruise, but those were quickly countermanded by another directive to proceed to the Solomon Islands. Yet Corry's gut feeling was that this was all a coverup for something far bigger. And he was about to be proved right! Told to rendezvous with and take on board a scientific team, Corry learned that the Shenandoah was at last going to be allowed to track down the alien invaders who were based beneath the sea--and this time they were going to bring one of the creatures back alive!

It is a trilogy and the publication date matches as the three books were written in 1993, 1994 and 1995.